# Why number of disparity must be divisible by 16?

Tags: opencv, stereoscopy, disparity-mapping

Why in OpenCv the disparity number, in the creation of disparity map, must be divisible by 16?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exactly are you doing, and which part of OpenCV requires disparity values that are multiples of 16?

Comment: If we use a block matching technique in openCv to build a disparity map there are some parameters that we can change to build the disparity map, for example minDisparity, SAD size, number of disparity and so on. As described here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereosgbm-stereosgbm number of disparity must be divisible by 16, but I don't understand it.